# Anaconda navigator and spyder not working

Tags: python, path, anaconda, spyder, conda

Today I tried installing the hyperspy library through the anaconda prompt using the code:

```
conda install hyperspy -c conda-forge
```

I got an error, that I do not have at the moment. Something with packages.

Now neither Anaconda Navigator nor Spyder will open.
The anaconda prompt does not recognize

```
conda
```

And the anaconda navigator looks as follows:

[anaconda navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7ggc.png)

Furthermore I tried to see if my PATH was missing anything, it doesn't seem like it:

[PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h33p.png)

Comment: It seems by installing that package from `conda-forge` you broke your Anaconda installation. That's not unusual because conda-forge and default packages are not binary compatible. The easiest solution is to remove and reinstall Anaconda again.

Comment: Next time, please create a conda environment to try packages from conda-forge.

Comment: Hello Carlos.  Thank you for the reply.  It all works now. I used the anaconda uninstall.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reinstalling spyder again, with the command: `conda install spyder`. 
 And it worked for me.
You can also start spyder with the command: `spyder -- show-console`.